How do I get React CountUp to count from a previous number?
I am new to React and am using the React CountUp to animate a number counting up, eg:
<CountUp end={totalAmount} />

This works - whenever totalAmount is changed CountUp will animate a count from 0 to whatever the new number is.
However, I want to animate it to count from whatever the previous number was. For example if the totalAmount changes from 70 to 100 I want the animate just to count from 70. As it is now, whatever totalAmount changes to it will always start at 0.
I see there is an update prop available, but I am unsure how to use it. I have tried:
<CountUp end={totalAmount} update={totalAmount} />

I see there is a way to do this in a "hook", but to be honest have no idea how to incorporate a hook into my broader React component.
Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction at all?

Try adding preserveValue={true}
<CountUp end={totalAmount} preserveValue={true}/>

Documentation

Use preserveValue boolean flag. It stores the previously ended number to start new animation from it.
Check Npm Link
<CountUp preserveValue={true} />


You can use the onEnd callback prop to update accessibility properties and set the number after each transition ends, using a hook like so:
const [Current, setCurrent] = React.useState(0); /* make sure you have {useCountUp} imported from countup and its is called */
        
const onEnd = () => {
      setCurrent(totalAmount); /*Whatever you want to do here really*/
};


/*Then set component up like this */
<CountUp end={totalAmount} start={Current} onEnd={onEnd}/>

Documentation
